# Backup on Debian interfering with other running programs

Tags: linux, backup, debian, cpu-usage

I've got a webserver on Debian 6. The system is also always running some processes sensitive to CPU usage. When I am using some of tools like `rsync` or `tar`, they are using CPU too much and my sensitive processes are experiencing trouble.

When I've tried to use CPU-Limit tool it was terrible experience when server went down.

I am looking for any lightweight backup tool that can create incremental backups.

Comment: Is your server multi-core? If so, have you tried running `taskset -pc 0 [rsync-pid]` after executing rsync, to limit it to the first (#0) core? (or is this the cpu-limit tool you mention?) Also try setting rsync's niceness.

Comment: Thank you! But, sure, we understand that backup is running by cron. Well, using taskset once will save this preference for further runs?

Comment: No; taskset runs once on that single process ID. You will have to add it in cron or in your script. (Possibly (1)background the rsync process, (2) run taskset and then (3) wait for the backgrounded rsync process to finish).